# Backbone Marionette console.log won't output

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

I am brand new to marionette and am following along with a textbook to build a simple app using marionette. I ran into this problem almost immediately, they telly you to put a console.log() in a function, except it doesn't show up in my browser when i run it. Here's the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();
ContactManager.on("initialize:after", function(){
console.log("ContactManager has started!");
});
ContactManager.start();
</script>
```

And here's the whole HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Marionette Contact Manager</title>
<link href="./assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./assets/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<span class="brand">Contact manager</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<p>Here is static content in the web page. You'll notice that it gets 21          replaced by our app as soon as we start it.</p>
</div>
<script src="./assets/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/vendor/json2.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/vendor/backbone.marionette.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();
ContactManager.on("initialize:after", function(){
console.log("ContactManager has started!");
});
ContactManager.start();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can do a console.log() outside of the ContactManager.on() code and it will work. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out the problem doing a little more research. Apparently they updated "initialize:after" to "start" without telling me. So there you have it if anyone else ever has this problem.

Comment: If you are able to figure out your own problem, you should post your solution as an actual answer.  It will help others that might be having the same problem as you because it will give a very clear and defined way to know that there is a solution and what it is.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the answer to my own question with a little research. Marionette has updated "initialize:after" to "start". For a full list of updates you can check here -->

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/changelog.md#v100-rc1-view-commit-logs